# Split string at word

Tags: php, preg-match, explode

I am trying to split a string a a specific words ie.

```
$whois = "Record last updated on 10-Apr-2011.Record expires on 08-Oct-2012.Record Expires on 08-Oct-2008.";

preg_split('/Expires|expires/', $whois, $expires);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($expires);
```

Scratching my head over this tried lots of different solutions need help. Just want the string to be split up like it does with explod but at the word.

So i would get something like this.

```
array([0]=>'expires on 08-Oct-2012.Record',[1]=>'Expires on 08-Oct-2008.')
```

help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the closest i could make

```
<?php
$whois = "Record last updated on 10-Apr-2011.Record expires on 08-Oct-2012.Record Expires on 08-Oct-2008.";
$expires = preg_split('/Expires|expires/', $whois);
array_shift($expires);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($expires);
?>
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  on 08-Oct-2012.Record 
    [1] =>  on 08-Oct-2008.
)
```

Comment: @DCHP Be aware that you are potentially introducing a problem when expires is between other words i.e. blaexpiresbla - this will also match. As a precautionary measure you should almost always put words inside word boundaries \bword\b.

Answer (score 0):

```
$whois = "Record last updated on 10-Apr-2011.Record expires on 08-Oct-2012.Record Expires on 08-Oct-2008.";
preg_match_all("/expires on [0-9]{2}-[a-z]{3}-[0-9]{4}/i", $whois, $expires);
print_r($expires[0]);
```

Close, but requires this strict format: "expires on 00-abc-0000"